# Convert java object into json by using javascript native function in gwt

Tags: javascript, json, gwt, jsni

I want to convert my java object into json by using JSNI i.e javascript native method in GWT. 
I dont want to use any external jar like Gson, jackson. I have dove following code.

```
public class JsonToJavaUsingJS implements EntryPoint {

  final Student student = new Student(5, "ajinkya", "patil");

  @Override
  public void onModuleLoad() {

    toJson(student);
  }

  public native void toJson(final Student student)
  /*-{
    var json = JSON.stringify(student);
    alert("json object: " + json);
  }-*/;
  }
```

but It does not convert java object into json string.
It gives follwing exception

> [ERROR] [jsontojavausingjs] - Uncaught exception escaped
>   com.google.gwt.event.shared.UmbrellaException: Exception caught: (null) @com.json.js.client.JsonToJavaUsingJS::toJson(Lcom/json/js/client/Student;)([Java object: com.json.js.client.Student@176073104]): null

plese help..!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you first try with GWT way if nothing found then go down to native JavaScript way.

> A simple way is defined here [GWT AutoBean framework](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/wiki/AutoBean) along with quick start and samples.

Read more about [Sharing objects between Java source and JavaScript](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit-doc-1-5/wiki/DevGuideMarshaling).

Comment: Does autobean supports List and map also?

Comment: Look at this section `JSON structures` mentioned at above link or [click here](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/wiki/AutoBean#visitCollectionProperty%28%29_/_visitMapProperty%28%29)

Answer (score 1):

GWT ain't able to convert Java objects into JavaScript objects.

But if you let your **Student** class extend the **[JavaScriptObject](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/core/client/JavaScriptObject.html)**.
You can then work with the Student class in both the native JavaScript world and the GWT world.

One other way is to create a method that creates a JSONObject and fills it with data from the **Student** class.

```
    JSONObject j = new JSONObject();
    j.put("firstName", new JSONString(firstName()));
    j.put("lastName", new JSONString(lastName()));
    return j; // or return j.toString();
```